# Highcharts Pie Custom Legend, possible?

Tags: html, highcharts, legend

I am working with Highcharts Pie chart.  I was using the legend on it, but noticed that if you start adding too many items to the legend; the pie itself becomes smaller and smaller.  So to correct that you would have to make the height of the container of the pie taller and taller to compensate for this.  Well, this is not practical if you are going to have numerous charts on one page and they are all 1000px tall to accommodate up to 50 legend items.

I see that it is not possible to "wrap" the legend and have it auto expand the container, again without making the pie smaller and smaller.  So I have two questions:

1) Is it possible to place the highcharts pie chart legend in it's own DIV so that it's height can auto expand and not worry about the pie becoming smaller?

2) Or, is it possible to create your own custom legend?  I have been looking at the click events for the highcharts, and I would like to know what the correct function code would be to have each item in the custom legend be a link, that when clicked on, moves the slice of the pie chart.  From my research, this does not seem possible.

Please let me know if you need any further clarification.

[(http://jsfiddle.net/Asd4A/192/)](http://jsfiddle.net/Asd4A/192/)

Here is the fiddle I was working with just for demo purposes.  Right now the legend shoots off the top of the screen.  I need it to align to the bottom (underneath the pie) and then auto expand the container div.  (see two questions above).

Thanks in advance for any help, and let me know if you need anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see [here](http://www.highcharts.com/documentation/changelog#highcharts) an option with paging has been added to it, so you if take a look again on your example it's being paged by highcharts.
I think the newest release should solve it.